# Wordpress Stop Page Pagnitation

Tags: php, wordpress

I am not to familiar with wordpress design, with that being said I do know a little PHP. Im trying to edit my theme so that it will *stop forming page pagination i.e. stop page forming ->page2->page3* after a certain numbers of posts have been added to the page

**My Question**

Scratching around my theme I believe this is the code responsible for creating the 2nd page, 3rd page and so forth.

```
//---------------------- Pagination ---------------

function kriesi_pagination($pages = '', $range = 4)
{  
     $showitems = ($range)+1;  

     global $paged;
     if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

     if($pages == '')
     {
         global $wp_query;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
         if(!$pages)
         {
             $pages = 1;
         }
     }   

     if(1 != $pages)
     {
         echo "<div class='pagination'>";
         //if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'> &laquo;</a>";
         if($paged > 1 ) echo "<a class='last' href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>PREVIOUS</a>";

         for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
         {
             if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
             {
                 echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a>";
             }
         }

         if ($paged < $pages ) echo "<a class='last' href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>NEXT</a>";  
         //if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'></a>";
         echo "</div>\n";
     }
}
```

**What I tried To do**

I believe the `$range` variable contains the number of posts before creating a second page, however after changing value of `$range` nothing has happened...

Commenting out the code - all posts on page 1 displays but all posts after that disappears...

Any advice here? Am I working with the wrong code snippet?

Comment: This looks like your theme's function: http://www.kriesi.at/archives/how-to-build-a-wordpress-post-pagination-without-plugin

Comment: That is it!! Thanks Im reading through it now, the only problem is I cant figure out how to change the param that sets the number of posts...

Comment: `$wp_query->max_num_pages`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paged is formed before the page is rendered so the code that controls the output of page numbers is too late.

You haven't identified whether this is a custom query, cpt etc so im assuming its the standard posts list. So modify as needed if not. This needs to go into your functions file.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'all_posts', 1 );

function all_posts($query){

    $query->set('posts_per_page', -1); // return all posts change this to the number you want
    $query->set('nopaging', true);//stop add rows...
    $query->set('no_found_rows', true); // dont count the rows to populate total posts count

}
```